# Reusing transformations between training and predictions

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'd like to apply stemming to my training data set. I can do this outside of tensorflow as part of training data prep, but I then need to do the same process on prediction request data before calling the (stored) model.

Is there a way of implementing this transformation in tensorflow itself so the transformation is used for both training and predictions?

This problem becomes more annoying if the transformation requires knowledge of the whole dataset, normalisation for example.

Answer (score 0):

Can you easily express your processing (e.g. stemming) as a tensorflow operation? If yes, then you can build your graph in a way that both your inputs and predictions can make use of the same set of operations. Otherwise, there isn't much harm in calling the same (non tensorflow) function for both pre-processing and for predictions.

Re normalisation: you would find the dataset statistics (means, variance, etc. depending on how exactly you are normalizing) and then hardcode them for the pre/post-processing so I don't think that's really an annoying case.